Как использовать id всех пользователей моего телеграм бота чтобы отправить им соответственно всем сообщение?
Пример: bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Привет, чем я могу тебе помочь?"), только не для того чтобы просто прислать человеку написавшему например команду, а прям всем кто использует чат. Конкретно я хочу чтобы бот поздравлял всех с новым годом когда он наступает

довольно популярный здесь вопрос.
